# Strategy to make django models with lots of memberfunctions more manageable?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a huge model because of its many member functions. I would like to organize the functions into separate classes according to their purpose, so everything is a bit more organized.

Using `OneToOneField` is not a good option for me, because my app heavily relies on query caching (with cacheops). And I noticed that getting the latest version of a data object (from db) may be attached to a an outdated OneToOneField (from cache). Also, the number of data members is not a problem, only the number of member functions. So I would prefer to use just one data model.

For example, I could do it this way:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # members

# separate member functions
class CustomModelFunctions:
    @staticmethod
    def some_function(my_model_instance):
        # logic

# call the function on the my_model obj 
#  instead of calling my_model.some_function()
CustomModelFunctions.some_function(my_model)
```

This works, but the problem is that these functions can not be used in django templates, since the my_model argument can not be passed. For example, I don't see how I could replace the following template code:

```
{% if my_model.some_function %}
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or a different approach to organize models with a lot of member functions?

Comment: Why not define these on the `MyModel`?

Comment: Because there are so many member functions that MyModel becomes cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a huge model because of its many member functions. I would like to organize the functions into separate classes according to their purpose, so everything is a bit more organized.

Probably the best way would be to work with a proxy, like:

```
class FunctionCategory(type):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self(obj)


class FunctionCategoryBase(metaclass=FunctionCategory):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj


# separate member functions
class FunctionCategory1(FunctionCategoryBase):
    def some_function11(self):
        # use self.obj
        return None

    def some_function12(self):
        # use self.obj
        return None


# separate member functions
class FunctionCategory2(FunctionCategoryBase):
    def some_function21(self):
        # use self.obj
        return None

    def some_function22(self):
        # use self.obj
        return None

    def some_function23(self):
        # use self.obj
        return None


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # members
    functions1 = FunctionCategory1
    functions2 = FunctionCategory2
```

Then you can use:

```
my_model_object.functions1.some_function12()
```

This will thus for `my_model_object.functions1` create a `FunctionCategory1` where it injects the model object.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. It essentially does the same thing as my original code, but without the `@staticmethod` (and a bit more elegant). 

   # models.py
   class MyModel(models.Model):
         # members

   # separate member functions
   class CustomModelFunctions:

       def __init__(self, my_model):
           self.my_model = my_model

       def some_function():
           # do sth with self.my_model

   custom_functions = CustomModelFunctions(my_model)
    custom_functions.some_function()

Comment: @FransClaessens: well the idea is that with some meta-programming (essentially the `__get__`), you thus automatically wrap the object model into the set of functions. In the template you thus can use `my_model_object.functions1.some_function12`. Furthermore you can define such `FunctionCategory`s in different modules, and just register these in the model(s) for which these are built.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Looks like a good solution.